# Error processing Instruction 1 when deploying Solana program?

Tags: solana

When I deploy a Solana program to devnet it works fine.

However, when I try to deploy the same program to production I get the following error:

```
Error: Deploying program failed: Error processing Instruction 1: custom program error: 0x1
There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(ExitStatus(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.
```

The command I am using is:

```
solana -k admin_key.json -u mainnet-beta program deploy target/deploy/pixels.so
```

This command works fine if I swap `mainnet-beta` with `devnet`.

It's worth noting that I can deploy to production (and I have) using:

`solana -k admin_key.json -u mainnet-beta deploy target/deploy/pixels.so`

Does anyone understand why the discrepancy between devnet and mainnet here?

Here's a link to the currently deployed program on main net:
https://explorer.solana.com/address/JBAnZXrD67jvzkWGgZPVP3C6XB7Nd7s1Bj7LXvLjrPQA

This was deployed using `solana [...] deploy` (versus the modern way of `solana [...] program deploy`).

You can see an example of a program deployed the modern way to dev net here:

https://explorer.solana.com/address/6uCCuJaQSQYGx4NwpDtZRyxyUvDMUJaVG1L6CmowgSTx?cluster=devnet

Answer (score 4):

Error 0x1 typically means that there isn't enough SOL in the payer key to cover the deployment.  You'll need to check that you have SOL on those keys on mainnet to properly do the deployment.

Comment: I have 2.67 SOL in the account. The intermediate buffer contains 1.394 SOL, which to me indicates I have excess SOL for the deployment.

Comment: What's also odd is that I can deploy to main-net using the other command (`solana -k admin_key.json -u mainnet-beta deploy target/deploy/pixels.so`), and that consumed around 1.394 SOL.

So this would mean deploying the new way costs over 1 extra SOL.

Comment: I've added a link to the deployed program (that was deployed the old way) to my main post.

Comment: Oh nevermind -- this makes sense. I understand now. The program data account requires 2.78 SOL which is exactly twice 1.39 SOL, which lines up with the fact that programs are deployed to program data accounts which are twice the size.